# modulo operation not returning correct value

Tags: c++, bit-shift, modulo, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve a problem in leetcode, I have cracked the algorithm for that specific problem, written pseudo code, and implemented the code in C++. Just one flaw remains in the solution, `modulo 1e9+7` the result.

The problem statetment : **Given an integer n, return the decimal value of the binary string formed by concatenating the binary representations of 1 to n in order, modulo 1e9 + 7.**

My approach :

[image: my approach to concatenation-of-consecutive-binary-numbers]

My code :

```
#include<math.h>
class Solution {
public:
    int concatenatedBinary(int n) {
        long long res = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int lShift = (int)ceil(log((double)(i+1+1)));
            res = res << lShift;
            //problem lies between these 
            res %= 1000000007;
            res += i+1;
            res %= 1000000007;
            cout << i << " - " << lShift << " - " << res << endl;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

I don't know why the modulo operation acting weirdly! Thanks in advance.

```
Example 1:

Input: n = 1
Output: 1
Explanation: "1" in binary corresponds to the decimal value 1. 

Example 2:

Input: n = 3
Output: 27
Explanation: In binary, 1, 2, and 3 corresponds to "1", "10", and "11".
After concatenating them, we have "11011", which corresponds to the decimal value 27.

Example 3:

Input: n = 12
Output: 505379714
Explanation: The concatenation results in "1101110010111011110001001101010111100".
The decimal value of that is 118505380540.
After modulo 109 + 7, the result is 505379714.
```

Comment: Your code is not concatenating the binary representations of `1...n`. My understanding of the question would have you performing the modulo operation *after* concatenation, not inside the loop.

Comment: I would say overflow issue.

Comment: @Jarod42 `res` is `long long` which is 64-bits.

Comment: Using floating-point operations in integer problems often causes problems.

Comment: BTW: it's "pseudo code", not "sudo code". "Pseudo" comes from Greek and means "not the real thing", "sudo" is a Unix tool that lets you execute a program as a different user.

Comment: Please be more specific than "acting weirdly".

Comment: What is the maximum value of `n`? For which value of `n` do you get false results?

Comment: if I don't implement modulo operation inside loop, some values may get overflown, so i'm doing that inside **Dai** , as **Jarod42** also mentioned the issue. But I'm using long so it shouldn't overflow according to my logic. **molbdnilo** I'm casting them back to INT and thanks for pointing out that mistake, I've changed to pseudo. **rustyx** added sample input output.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad The problem is that floating point lacks precision. No amount of casting can restore it.

Comment: The problem is not in the modulo, but in the fact that the log should be in base 2!! Replace `log` with `log2`.

Comment: @Damien you solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem was that you use `log` instead of a logarithm in base 2: `log2`.

Besides, it is generally better to avoid floating point calculations in such a situation.

In the following code, I have included a corrected version of your code,
and a new simple version without any floating point calculation

```
#include<cmath>
#include <iostream>

class Solution {
public:
    int concatenatedBinary(int n) {
        long long res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int lShift = (int)ceil(log2((double)(i+1+1)));
            res = res << lShift;
            //problem lies between these 
            res %= 1000000007;
            res += i+1;
            res %= 1000000007;
            std::cout << i+1 << " - " << lShift << " - " << res << std::endl;
        }
        return res;
    }
    int concatenatedBinary_nolog(int n) {
        long long res = 0;
        int lShift = 1;
        int pow2 = 2;
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            if (i >= pow2) {
                lShift++;
                pow2 *= 2;
            }
            res = res << lShift;
            res %= 1000000007;
            res += i;
            res %= 1000000007;
            std::cout << i << " - " << lShift << " - " << res << std::endl;
        }
        return res;
    }
};

int main(){
    Solution sol;
    for (int n: {1, 3, 12}) {
        int answer = sol.concatenatedBinary(n);
        std::cout << n << " : " << answer << "\n";
        answer = sol.concatenatedBinary_nolog(n);
        std::cout << n << " : " << answer << "\n";
    }
}
```